# Bootstrap odd column centered

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know if its possible but I'd like to have the odd column centered instead of align to the left:

```
<div class=col-md-4 col-sm-6>...</div>
<div class=col-md-4 col-sm-6>...</div>
<div class=col-md-4 col-sm-6>...</div>
```

Will have three columns nicely on medium or larger screens. While on small screens, there will be two columns with and a third stacked on the bottom. I'd like that third column to be centered instead of left aligned. Is that possible without js (I can think of a couple ways to do this with js, but I'd rather do it with css only)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
<div class=col-md-4 col-sm-6>...</div>
<div class=col-md-4 col-sm-6>...</div>
<div class=col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3>...</div>
```

`col-sm-offset-3` will insert an offset 3 on the third column, so center the div.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, offsets are used to center columns. Try this...

```
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-offset-3">...</div>
```

This will center the column *only* on smaller widths.

http://bootply.com/94161